# How to move multiple images separately using SFML mouse movements?

Tags: c++, graphics, mouseevent, sfml, mousepress

Below is my code which displays two images inside a window.

Now by moving mouse both the images move together but how should i access them separately?

```
int main()
{
// Let's setup a window
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML ViewTransformation");

// Let's create the background image here, where everything initializes.
sf::Texture BackgroundTexture;
sf::Sprite bd;
sf::Vector2u TextureSize;  //Added to store texture size.
sf::Vector2u WindowSize;   //Added to store window size.

 if(!BackgroundTexture.loadFromFile("bg1.jpg"))
    {
      return -1;
    }
else
{
TextureSize = BackgroundTexture.getSize(); //Get size of texture.
WindowSize = window.getSize();             //Get size of window.

float ScaleX = (float) WindowSize.x / TextureSize.x;
float ScaleY = (float) WindowSize.y / TextureSize.y;     //Calculate scale.

bd.setTexture(BackgroundTexture);
bd.setScale(ScaleX, ScaleY);      //Set scale.
}
// Create something simple to draw
sf::Texture texture;
texture.loadFromFile("background.jpg");
sf::Sprite background(texture);
sf::Vector2f oldPos;
bool moving = false;

sf::View view = window.getDefaultView();

while (window.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                if (event.mouseButton.button == 0) {
                    moving = true;
                    oldPos = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y));
                }
                break;
            case  sf::Event::MouseButtonReleased:

                if (event.mouseButton.button == 0) {
                    moving = false;
                }
                break;
            case sf::Event::MouseMoved:
                {
                    if (!moving)
                        break;

                    const sf::Vector2f newPos = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseMove.x, event.mouseMove.y));

                    const sf::Vector2f deltaPos = oldPos - newPos;
                    view.setCenter(view.getCenter() + deltaPos);
                    window.setView(view);



 oldPos = window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseMove.x, event.mouseMove.y));
                    break;
                }
 }
    }

    window.clear(sf::Color::White);
    window.draw(bd);
    window.draw(background);

    window.display();
}
}
```

Also I would love to hear the suggestions where I could find such examples with proper insights and good explanation as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. I answered the question about the moving view. If you have multiple image (not including the background image) you need to either check the click and z-order or find another way to select an image, e.g. by pressing the 1, 2, 3 etc. key and then only move this image.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are moving the view and not the sprite itself:

```
view.setCenter(view.getCenter() + deltaPos);
window.setView(view);
```

Instead you should move the sprite. So exchange the two lines above with this line and it should work

```
bd.setPosition(bd.getPosition() - deltaPos);
```